# convert a tensor written as string to tensor

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

I have a CSV in which some document embeddings in form of tensor are stored.
Something like this:

```
>>> data.loc[0]['Q_emd_list']
'tensor([ 0.1210, -1.1949,  0.1806,  ...,  0.3578, -0.1209,  0.4065])'
```

but as seen this is a string. how can i convert this to tensor. i tried using ast, but that doesnt help.

```
import ast
q_emd = ast.literal_eval(data.loc[0]['Q_emd_list'])
```

this gives an error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/anaconda/envs/py38_default/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 99, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py38_default/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 98, in _convert
    return _convert_signed_num(node)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py38_default/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 75, in _convert_signed_num
    return _convert_num(node)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py38_default/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 66, in _convert_num
    _raise_malformed_node(node)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py38_default/lib/python3.8/ast.py", line 63, in _raise_malformed_node
    raise ValueError(f'malformed node or string: {node!r}')
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7fbe6203f580>
```

Any help in this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO :)
There is a problem with the way you stored the embeddings, it's the loss of some information in the middle of each array (I mean what is substituted with `...`). The issue prevents you from evaluating the string.

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` method can convert string to a variable.

Try:

```
import torch
temp_string = 'tensor([0.1210, -1.1949, 0.1806, 0.3578, -0.1209, 0.4065])'
temp_tensor = eval("torch." + temp_string)
print(temp_tensor, temp_tensor.shape)
```